# NAS + Torrent + XBMC?

Tags: kodi, file-sharing

Could I try to setup the raspberry B+ as a NAS (with Bittorrent sync) and a torrent server and use it as media center with xbmc on a TV? Or it would be too busy to manage all these stuff?

Answer (score 1):

As short answer, what I can say from my experience is, as long as you do not use `samba` (free implementation of [SMB/CIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) or [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) for the NAS part, that should be fine. Those two features are known to be CPU intensive and could be a bottleneck for the RPi.

XBMC can run quite smoothly on a Pi. [`transmission-daemon`](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/transmission-daemon) (the daemon client for the popular BitTorrent Transmission) has low CPU/RAM footprint as well.

Comment: I suppose you could try it out.
It will work with NTFS and samba, but without an overclock I doubt it will work satisfactory when using samba and something else simultaneously.  samba reaches speeds of about 3,xx MB/s with CPU load maxing out when used with a mounted ntfs disk

Comment: @Havnar The trick is XBMC would be already running, and although it can display HD videos smoothly, it is quite CPU intensive (less than `samba` though). So, running `samba` in the same time could greatly slow down the rendering and cause the video to 'flicker'.

Comment: that was my point :) 
But, when OP would not be using both services at the same time, I guess it would not be a problem.

Comment: @Havnar Well I read too fast your comment... Sorry :-S But, as you already wrote, it is something to experiment, and from which OP should share the results with the RPi.SE community :-)